# Anaconda Navigatorが開けない

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

Anaconda Navigatorが起動しなくなりました。
アイコンをクリックしても砂時計が出るだけですぐに消えてしまう状況です。
OSはWindows、Anaconda Navigatorのバージョンは最新です。
ご回答、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

以下は Anaconda Prompt で試したログです。

```
(base) C:\Users\owner>anaconda navigator --reset
usage: anaconda [-h] [--disable-ssl-warnings] [--show-traceback] [-v] [-q]
                [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE]
                ...
anaconda: error: argument : invalid choice: 'navigator' (choose from 'auth', 'label', 'channel', 'config', 'copy', 'download', 'groups', 'login', 'logout', 'move', 'notebook', 'package', 'remove', 'search', 'show', 'upload', 'whoami')

(base) C:\Users\owner>
```

### 追記

ハイフンを入れてやってみたのですが、上手くいきませんでした。

```
(base) C:\Users\owner>anaconda-navigator --reset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 172, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

(base) C:\Users\owner>
```

##またまた追記

①全てをアップデートしました。
②その上でresetを試みましたが前と同じエラーが出ました。
③anaconda-navigatorとコマンドを打つと、下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
(base) C:\Users\owner>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 205, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

④conda list anaconda-navigatorを実行すると下のようになりました。

```
(base) C:\Users\owner>conda list anaconda-navigator
# packages in environment at C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda-navigator        1.9.6                    py36_0
```

⑤conda list qtを実行すると下のようになりました。

```
(base) C:\Users\owner>conda list qt
# packages in environment at C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h6538335_2
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.5.3                    py36_0
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py36_0
qtpy                      1.5.2                    py36_0
```

⑥conda list pysideを実行すると下のようになりました。

```
(base) C:\Users\owner>conda list pyside
# packages in environment at C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

Comment: 回答者がコピー＆ペーストをやりやすくしたり、検索にひっかかりやすくするため、ログ部分はスクリーンショットでなくて出ている文字列をコピーしてそのままペーストして頂けると助かります。ペーストしたログをカーソルで範囲選択し、エディタ上部の `{}` ボタンを押すことでコードブロックとして装飾することもできます。次回からはそのようにお願いいたします<(_ _)>

Comment: Anaconda Prompt の上でオプション無しで単に `anaconda-navigator` と打ったときに出るエラーも教えて頂けますか？

Comment: Anaconda Prompt で `conda list anaconda-navigator` および `conda list qt`、`conda list pyside` を実行したときの結果を教えて頂けませんか？　このコマンドは今の Anaconda Navigator と Qt のバージョン情報などを教えてくれます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。以後気を付けます追記に結果を書きましたのでご確認いただけたらと思います。親身に回答くださり恐縮です。どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

### コマンド名について

`anaconda navigator` でなくて `anaconda-navigator` (間にハイフンが入る) です。

### `No module named 'PySide'` について

このエラーは、Anaconda Navigator が使っている依存ライブラリのバージョンの齟齬が上手くとれなかったときに出ることがあるようです。同時に出ているエラーメッセージ `No Qt bindings could be found` を見ると、特に GUI を管理する Qt というライブラリのバージョンがどこかのタイミングで古くなってしまい、Anaconda Navigator から使えなくなってしまった可能性があります。たとえば conda-forge から PySide をインストールすると Qt 5 ではなく Qt 4 がインストールされてしまってこのエラーが出るようです。

そこで、まずは `conda info` コマンドを Anaconda Prompt 上で打って、バージョンを確認してみてください。古ければ `conda update` でアップデートしてください。面倒くさければ、以下のコマンドで全てのライブラリのバージョンを一気に上げることができます。

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

同様のエラーは Anaconda Navigator のバグ報告ページに [い](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9916) [く](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9072) [つ](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9158) [も](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10118) 上げられているため、ハマる人の多いエラーのようです。上のコマンドで解決しなければ、[バグ報告ページ](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues)からエラーメッセージで検索してみて、他の解決策を探ってみてください。

Comment: 回答(と質問の編集)ありがとうございます。ハイフンをいれてやってみたのですが、追加した画像のとおり上手くいきませんでした。

Comment: 回答からしばらく経っておりますが、私も全く同じ問題に直面しました。nekketsuuuさんの回答にある い く つ もの「い」のリンクにあるpyqt5のバージョンを指定してインストールしたところ直りました。ちなみに私は5.12.1を使っていましたが、5.11にダウングレードしました。ここで解決したかどうか記載されていなかったので参考までにコメントしました。